# Setting properties dynamically in react based on value of other properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I am writing a REACT application to show some reviews. 
Each reviews has two properties likes and dislikes. 
The state of my main component looks like

```
state = {
    listings: [
        { key: 'key6', listingCity: 'City_Name', listingTitle: 'Restaurant_Name', likes: '3', dislikes: '1', listingBodyText: 'Review_Text' },
        { key: 'key7', listingCity: 'City_Name2', listingTitle: 'Restaurant_Name2', likes: '13', dislikes: '9', listingBodyText: 'Review_Text2' }
    ]
};
```

I want to add another property which is like a score for each restaurant, and this will be difference between likes and dislikes. 
For the two restaurants in my example state, 
1. likes - 3, dislikes - 1 -- Score = 2
2. likes - 13 , dislikes - 9 -- Score = 4

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to generate this score. 
One option is I add another property for each restaurant called score and initialise it to 0 in the state. Then in the `componentDidMount()` hook, calculate this value. 
this will work well for the initial calculation, but now every time a user would like / dislike I would have to call this function to have the updated score.

Is there a way to define a property in the state as a difference of two other properties. 
In my case, define score = likes - dislikes

My main goal with this question is to try and understand what would be the recommended approach for this kind of problem.

Comment: You can do this: `state.listings.map(val=>{
    val.score = val.likes - val.dislikes;
    return val;
})`

Comment: @gorak - so I would initialise it as 0 and then calculate it during component mount and every time, any like / dislikes is updated?

Comment: Where do you intend to use this property?
If you already have likes and dislikes, then you can just use them directly?
Like so `likes-dislikes`?

Comment: @UtsavPatel when I am displaying the reviews on the final listing pages, I want to order them based on this rating. so I am trying to figure out if I should do this on the fly or store in the state.

Comment: @VikG You should just do them on the fly.

In this use case I do not see any benefit in creating another property.

Comment: thanks @UtsavPatel I am sort of leaning towards that option myself. now I have both approaches validated, will give them a try and see how it turns out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate function for this and you can pass key of each restaurant:

```
const calScore = (key) => {
  const listings = (this?.state?.listings??[]).map(listing => {
     if(listing.key === key) {
       return {
           ...listing,
           score: listing?.likes - listing?.dislikes
       }
     } else {
        return {...listing}
     }
  })
  this.setState({ listings })
}
```

You can call this function after every like/dislike click

Comment: thanks for sharing this @shubham-chitransh, I will add these to my like / dislike handlers.